# Exchange 2013 User Roles Assignment

Tags: exchange, exchange-2013

Good Morning

I'm trying to give a couple users the ability to create, modify and view distribution groups and modify, view, remove, and add members to distribution groups they own.
To accomplish this i've went into the ECP>permissions> user roles and created the new role.  Then I went to Recipients and selected the correct user account, went to mailbox features and selected the new Role Assignment Policy. 
From what i've read this should be an immediate change once you refresh the options page in OWA.  For some reason though the user i'm trying to assign this policy to still doesn't have the Groups listing on the left side such as the image below.

Any idea what i'm missing?  Why doesn't the user have the groups option in OWA?

Here is what it looks like.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I rarely see the change immediately. Like many things with Exchange it takes some time to catch up. Therefore I would wait a bit longer to see if the change is seen.

Answer (score 0):

Click **Other** option which is listed as the last one in Option page, then click ***Go to the earlier version*** in the right pane. You will see **groups** in the list. Select **groups**, then you will be able to check and edit the groups you own.

Make sure you select the MyDistributionGroups and MyDistributionGroupMembership for the new role assignment policy, like below:

[image]

Comment: I do not have those options.  I've updated the original questions to include a couple pictures.

Comment: I added a snapshot for your reference.

Comment: Thank you for continuing to assist.  Yes I do have those options selected for "MyDistributionGroups" and "MYDistributionGroupMembership"